# Can't open Telerik Kendo window twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, telerik, kendo-window

I have a Kendo window which is defined as follows:

```
 With Html.Kendo().Window().Name("tranferwindow")
    .Title("Select Transfer Destination")
    .Content("")
    .Resizable()
    .Modal(True)
    .Events(Function(events) events.Open("WindowToCenter"))
    .Events(Function(events) events.Refresh("transferopen"))
    .Draggable()
    .Width(400)
    .Visible(False)
    .Render()
    End With
```

The window is opened each time by using the refresh and passing a new URL.This is to allow dynamic data to be displayed dependent on what the user clicked on a grid.

```
 function transferitem(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    wwindow.data("kendoWindow").open(); //Display waiting window while refresh happens
    var twindow = $("#tranferwindow")
    twindow.data("kendoWindow").refresh('/Home/TransferList?agentid=' + agentid + '&tenantid='    + tenantid + '&SessionID=' + dataItem.MediaID);
    }
```

The Window is opened at the end of the refresh event to make sure the user doesn't see the previous content.

```
 function transferopen() {
 wwindow.data("kendoWindow").close();  //Close the 'wait' window
 var twindow = $("#tranferwindow")
 twindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
 }
```

This all works well and the window can be closed and reopened as often as I like.

However I needed to access the resize event of the window from within the Partial View to resize the Grid which is inside the window. To achieve this I added the following to the partial view that is returned from the url.

```
 $("#tranferwindow").kendoWindow({
 resize: function (e) {
  // resizeGrid();
   }
     });
```

Adding this event mapping causes the issue where I cannot open the Window more than once.
I assume I need to 'unregister' for the event somehow before closing?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: much cleaner and no VB Razor needed :)

I changed the approach to create a new window each time I wanted to display one.

I created a div to hold the Window.

```
<div id="windowcontainer"></div>
```

Then when the user selected a command on the grid , I create the whole window appending it to the div. The key here is the this.destroy in the deactivate event.

```
         function transferitem(e) {
         var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
         $("#windowcontainer").append("<div id='tranferwindow'></div>");

         var mywindow = $("#tranferwindow")
         .kendoWindow({
             width: "400px",
             title: "Select Transfer Destination",
             visible: false,
             content: '/Home/TransferList?agentid=' + agentid + '&tenantid=' + tenantid + '&SessionID=' + dataItem.MediaID,
             deactivate: function () {
                 this.destroy();
             },
             open: WindowToCenter,
             refresh:transferopen
         }).data("kendoWindow");
         mywindow.refresh();
         }
```

Then on the refresh function

```
     function transferopen() {
     var twindow = $("#tranferwindow")
     twindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
 }
```

Now I can have the event binding inside the Partial View which works fine and the window can be re opened as many times as I want. :)

Update: Adding the event binding inside the Partial View stops 'Modal' from working. Working on trying to fix this...